# Filter tweets by client name

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to filter tweets  results by client name like - using source operator.
I'm trying to do it with a a client named "single platform" , to get tweets like http://twitter.com/#!/phoenixparknyc/status/43340419475570688 but the search doesn't seems to work (tried with quotes as well)
http://twitter.com/#!/search/source%3Asingle%20platform%20Specials%2FEvents%20 
Any idea how to make the search works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to handle multi word sources is to remove the spaces. For example `Twitter for Android` becomes `source:twitterforandroid`. Unfortunately searching by source is pretty unreliable and generally doesn't work with low volume clients. My guess is it will eventually work for your client but who knows when.

http://twitter.com/#!/search/special%20source%3Asingleplatform